# How to use created module in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have alredy 3 grey hair from this. Rails4.0/ruby 1.9.3. I have file `test.rb` in directory `/lib/moduletest/test`. test.rb looks like this:

```
module Moduletest
   class test
   end
end
```

How can I instantiate this class in my controller? How should I use the require command? Moduletest::test.new() ?

Comment: You have to put this into the autoload path.

Comment: I have `require moduletest/test` in my controller and autoload is `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib", "#{config.root}/lib/**/"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first may I suggest you to use "foobar" instead of "test". "test" looks really like, test.

Back to question, there are two ways to use it in controller, given you have already loaded the module correctly as per comments.

The first is to explicitly include it. Preferred

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include ModuleFoo

  def index
    bar # Use ModuleFoo's method directly
    #...
  end
end
```

The second is to hook the extension in Rails loading

```
# ModuleFoo
module ModuleFoo
  def bar
  end
end

if defined? ActionController::Base
  ActionController::Base.class_eval do
    include ModuleFoo
  end
end

# Controller
class SomethingController < ApplicationController
  def some_method
    bar # use this directly
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the lib directory into your autoload path. So Rails load your file on startup:

`config/application.rb` and add:

`config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)`

Comment: I have there `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib", "#{config.root}/lib/**/"]`. So the problem is how to create the class.